# Enabling floating point support with TMS570

Tags: threadx, azure-rtos

We are porting Azure OS https://github.com/azure-rtos/threadx/tree/v6.1.11_rel
to TMS570 hardware https://github.com/azure-rtos/threadx/tree/v6.1.11_rel/ports/cortex_r5.
We have requirement of floating point calculations on application side. Can anyone tell me how do we can enable floating point support.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure floating point is enabled in the compiler and assembler options when you build ThreadX and your application. For each thread using the VFP, call tx_thread_vfp_enable() before using the VFP.